# Downloading NetCDF files with R: Manually works but the downloaded file is smaller

Tags: r, download, netcdf

I am trying to download NetCDF files from:
https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/NMME/prob/netcdf/

When I manually download the files I got a file of about 5000 Kb, when it is downloaded with the code below I got a file of 119 Kb and it is not usable.

```
now <- as.Date(Sys.Date())
now <- paste0(substr(now,1,4),substr(now,6,7))
filename <- paste0('prate.',now,'.prob.adj.seas',".nc")
root <- 'https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/NMME/prob/netcdf/'
download.file(root, filename,mode = "wb")
```

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the arguments of `download.file()` incorrectly. Try

```
## your code
now <- as.Date(Sys.Date())
now <- paste0(substr(now,1,4),substr(now,6,7))
filename <- paste0('prate.',now,'.prob.adj.seas',".nc")
root <- 'https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/NMME/prob/netcdf/' # main_url

## changes
path <- getwd() # example of donwload directory
download.file(url = paste0(root, filename), 
              destfile = file.path(path, basename(filename)))
```

See `?download.file`

1. The first argument to `download.file()` is a `url`, i.e.,
   `"https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/NMME/prob/netcdf/prate.202311.prob.adj.seas.nc"`.
2. Then specify `destfile`, i.e., the local path, a combination of download directory and file name. On Mac OS X it looks like `"/Users/YourUsername/Desktop/prate.202311.prob.adj.seas.nc"`.

```
download.file(url = paste0(root, filename), 
              destfile = file.path(path, basename(filename)))
```

equals

```
download.file(
  url = "https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/NMME/prob/netcdf/prate.202311.prob.adj.seas.nc",
  destfile = "/Users/YourUsername/Desktop/prate.202311.prob.adj.seas.nc")
```

I think `mode = "wb"` is not necessary. Haven't checked.

Comment: Effect of omitting `mode = "wb"` is only visible in Windows where storing files in text mode (default) will corrupt binaries.